# Java Script - Compare "this" with String

Tags: javascript, string, compare, this

This is something I couldnt find out through googling sadly. I have no clue how to compare my this with a string. 
So for some context: I have a table, and i want to compare the text in the td field with a string. "This" is my td field, and i dont know how to compare. My best bet was with

```
if(this.value == BenutzergruppeString2){ }
```

but this sadly doesnt work.

This is where i set my this:

```
$('td[id^="EDITDialog"]').each(function(){
let that = $(this);
    $(this).find('i#EditAK').off('click').on('click',function(){
```

and this is where i want to use it. First i am construction my string via the loop and afterwards i want to compare the two:

```
for(let keykey = 0; keykey < key; keykey++){ //key ist max weil grössster eintrag letzter ist
    firstBG = 0;
    for(var keyBenGrp = 0; keyBenGrp < GlobalVarUS[keykey]["benutzergruppe"].length; keyBenGrp++){
        if(firstBG == 0){
            var BenutzergruppeString2 = GlobalVarUS[keykey]["benutzergruppe"][keyBenGrp];
            firstBG++;
        }else{
            BenutzergruppeString2 = BenutzergruppeString2 +";" + GlobalVarUS[keykey]["benutzergruppe"][keyBenGrp];                                          
        }
    }
    if(this.value == BenutzergruppeString2){
        let tempuro = $("<tr><td><input value='"+GlobalVarUS[keykey]["pk_ak_id"]+"' ></input></td><td><input value='"+GlobalVarUS[keykey]["kategorie"]+"' ></input></td></tr>");
        tempuro.appendTo("#table_zf");  
    }
}
```

I hope some of you can help me. Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: someone asked whats inside the td field, so I'll post a picure of it. When i press one of the buttons to the right, a dialog window opens and i want to compare the field(Benutzergruppe) next to the button with the String.

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<td>` elements do not have a `value`. Try using the `innerHTML` attribute instead.

```
if(this.innerHTML == BenutzergruppeString2){ }
```

Comment: What does the content of your `td` look like?

Comment: I mean what does the code look like, if the `td` contains HTML tags, extracting only the text will be more difficult.

Comment: Ah but it looks like you are using jQuery already. So I would suggest getting the text from the `td` like so: `$(this).text()`. It is a jQuery function that will remove all the markup from the `innerHTML` of an element.

Comment: I generate the fields, by appending a temp to the table, so that whats in the table can be generated dynamically. In the td field, is only a simple string. A string i construct the same way i constructed the string in the example code i gave by adding several strings onto each other to get a bigger one

Comment: Are you sure `this` is what you think it is? See a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8yfze1bL/

Answer (score 0):

If `this` is a `td` element and you want to get value of `input` element contained in it, replace `this.value` with

```
$('input')[0].value
```